# Different language files not compiled on Android

Tags: android, file

I have a couple of files in the drawable folder that are in Russian - xxxxxx.jpg, where x's are Russian characters. During compile, Android does not recognize the files. Is there any way to fix that?

No disrespect, but is there a way to fix it? Maybe import an extra file? Override it? Put into another folder? Jinx it?

Answer (score 1):

Rename Files using only **[a-z0-9_.]**

**keep in mind first character must be an alphabet !**

Answer (score 0):

The res folder only accepts filenames containing `[a-z0-9_.]`

You will have to rename your files to use only lowercase English letters, the digits 0-9, an underscore and a full stop. There is no way around this, and you cannot have Russian characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

`res` folder supports the files with names containing `[a-z0-9_.]` If any of your files contains the characters other than the above listed, should be renamed.

Comment: No, all the answers are just a citation for the error that I get when I put the files in drawable. Android tells me that I can only use those characters. My question was if there was any way I can override it. Maybe put a different folder? Maybe edit the regex?